# midsigma not varsigma

Tags: fonts, greek

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{Νέαρχος} \d{ }\d{} \textgreek{παρεπ\lbrkοιησ\rbrkά-}
\textgreek{τὸ προ\d{σ}\d{κ}ύ\d{ν}\d{η}\d{μ}α}}
\end{document}
```

Dear all,
I have the above code which gives me some problems (using latex). basically it prints the sigma as a final sigma (ς) and not as a midsigma (σ) when there is a command after it.

This does not happen when I remove \usepackage{palatino}, but I would really like to keep using it. how can I keep palatino as a font and have it print σ for example in προσκύνημα and not προςκύνημα as it does keeping that? 
thank you very much

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using texshop on mac (I hope this is what you mean)

Comment: No, that's not what I wanted to know. What does the first line in the .log file say? Something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`

Comment: Sorry. This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)

Comment: Your TeX distribution is largely outdated.

Comment: thanks. excuse my ignorance, please: if I update, will the rest of all I have done with that distribution be still usable? will that solve the problem? thanks again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13091/discussion-between-pietro-maria-liuzzo-and-egreg)

Comment: Palatino is `palatino` is obsolete. Recommended replacement (`l2tabuen`) is `\usepackage{mathpazo}
  \usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
  \usepackage{courier}`. It is not actually this font combination per se. It appears to be this combined with `teubner`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TeX Live 2011 is quite outdated. If your project's status doesn't allow for an easy upgrade, then the best thing you can do is to add `\noboundary` after a non final sigma, in those situations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{Νέαρχος} \d{ }\d{} \textgreek{παρεπ\lbrkοιησ\noboundary\rbrkά-}
\textgreek{τὸ προ\d{σ\noboundary}\d{κ}ύ\d{ν}\d{η}\d{μ}α}
\end{document}
```

(Tested on TeX Live 2011)

On the other hand, the following works without a glitch on TeX Live 2013

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
Abcdef \textgreek{Νέαρχος} \d{ }\d{} \textgreek{παρεπ\lbrkοιησ\rbrkά-}
\textgreek{τὸ προ\d{σ}\d{κ}ύ\d{ν}\d{η}\d{μ}α}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `palatino` is obsolete. Recommended replacement (`l2tabuen`) is `\usepackage{mathpazo}
  \usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
  \usepackage{courier}`.